# Unable to append the data with promise.push in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display all the settings and number of employees in that setting in their respective tables.So I want to make two different http (Get) calls and append those results. So one of my friends suggest me to go with promise.push. I tried in differnt ways but I failed.

```html
<html>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="setting in createAttendance.AtSettings">
      <td>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p class="leavesettingpara">
            <strong><span class="parastrong"></span>{{setting.name}}</strong>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            
            <p class="leavesettingpara">{{settings.numOfEmployees}} Employees</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <p class="leavesettingpara">{{setting.date | date:'medium'}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <p class="leavesettingpara">By {{setting.createdName}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Controller:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('settingsDisplayController', ['$state', 'attendanceSettingsService'

    function($state, attendanceSettingsService) {
      attendanceSettingsService.getSettings().then(function(data) {
        vm.AtSettings = data;
        console.log("organization" + data);
      });
    }
  ]);
```

Major problem I was faced is "I want parent child relation.On success of first http call with that result.id we want to make second http call"

Service:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('attendanceSettingsService', ['$q', '$http', '$state',
    function($q, $http, $state) {
      this.getSettings = function() {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http.get('api/organizationName').success(function(result) {
          var promises = [];
          var defer = $q.defer();
          var res = [];
          promises.push($http.get('api/organizations/' + result.id + '/attendanceProfileSettings').success(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
          }));
          console.log(res);
          promises.push($http.get('api/setting/' + res.id + '/employees'));


          $q.all(promises).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            d.resolve(data);

          }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(" failure...." + status);
          });

          return defer.promise;

        });

        return d.promise;
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: You probably want to use promise chaining.  Check this out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues

Answer (score 0):

This strategy is used when you have many parallels promises, and wants a callback when all promises have been resolved successfully.

What you may want, it's called *promise chaining* which calls the next promise with the answer of the previous. Example:

```
travelService
            .getDeparture( user )                                           // Request #1
            .then( function( departure )
            {
                $scope.departure = departure;                               // Response Handler #1
                return travelService.getFlight( departure.flightID );       // Request #2
            })
            .then( function( flight )
            {
                $scope.flight = flight;                                     // Response Handler #2
                return weatherService.getForecast( $scope.departure.date ); // Request #3
            })
            .then( function( weather )
            {
                $scope.weather = weather;                                   // Response Handler #3
            });
```

This is a sample from a promise chaining guide you may want to look at: http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/